# Mac OSX Terminal Vim displays javascript code with weird and horrid shade

Tags: vim, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I develop javascript and just recently I found that I still love to use Terminal Vim instead of MacVim. Then I was totally annoyed when I opened my usual javascript file in the Terminal Vim: the statements of the code are irregularly highlighted with a mysterious color.

[image]

Just to clarify that other file types I have opened (e.g. c, html etc.) do not have the problem. I have scoured website but I could not find an answer. This is just so unacceptable, could someone help me out. A million thanks!

My .vimrc screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us some code that has this problem so we can try it out?

Comment: The last status message states: `'require' was used before it was defined`. Do you have any plugins that would be causing such a message. Is this related to your highlighting issue?

Comment: @glts I solved this problem. See my own solution

Comment: @PeterRincker Yes! I found out later that I was using a vim JSLint plugin; I deleted it and it worked. The plugin has some bug that I could not disable it as I thought I did. https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

- You appear to be using Syntastic.
- The first line with the red background seems to be marked as an error.
- The `Error` highlight group is very often set to use a red background.

My conclusion is that what you see is exactly what you should see. It is ugly on purpose and *designed* to look like that: you don't want to miss errors, do you?

However, Syntastic can be set to not use the `Error` highlighting to mark errors but the "signs" feature instead which is *a lot* less ugly.

You should have read the Syntastic documentation as it is all explained in plain english:

```
:help syntastic-error-signs
```

Also, `set background=dark` is not very useful (it doesn't change the background color, if that's what you want) and can be removed safely from your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Just another case of not reading the doc and complaining about a perfectly normal and documented behavior with a perfectly documented "solution". "unacceptable", really?

Comment: Hi romaini, I did not use "Syntactic" but your comment gave me a hint about the "Error" highlight so I went back to my bundle folder and found that I was using a Vim JSLint plugin. However, this plugin seems to have some bug that it cannot be disabled which led to the problem I described. I deleted it completely and the problem was gone.

Comment: None taken. I agree that reading documentation carefully is an obligation sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was this plugin [jslint.vim](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim) that caused the text to be highlighted. The problem is that this plugin could not be disabled properly which I thought I did. Thanks to the hint of @romaini, [syntactic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is a better plugin to check code errors and make proper configuration.

As a side note, for those who would like to use vim [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) color scheme, please use the [solarized](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) terminal color scheme first. Otherwise the color scheme won't be displayed properly.

Thank you for all of your comments and answers! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your colorscheme. Open the file in Vim, then do

```
:colorscheme blink
```

To cycle through all possible colourschemes, type `:colorscheme`, then a space, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. When you reach a colorscheme that sounds promising, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and see if the text looks OK. Keep doing this until you find a colorscheme that you like.

Once you have found a colorscheme that you like, copy its name, and put the following in your .vimrc:

```
colorscheme name
```

(`name` is the name of the colorscheme you like.)

My favourite colorscheme is `blink`, but there are many good ones. You can even go online and download new ones if the defaults are not good enough.

Comment: Thank you. I did use some colorscheme.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the syntax are not recognized correctly. Could you try:

:set filetype=javascript

Comment: No it's recognized!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to look at to make things look better (will change colors not highlighting). Make sure that your terminal reports itself as xterm-256colors. You can check this by typing `echo $TERM`.

If it doesn't return xterm-256colors go to Preferences -> Settings -> Advanced (tab) on the profile you are using.

Change the drop down at the top to xterm-256colors.

Comment: Hi FDinoff, thank you! I had already added that setting and echo $TERM also returns "xterm-256colors".